# Select first match between two patterns.Restart search if a 3rd pattern is found using sed/awk/grep

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I am struggling with the following task(I've been searching for answer for a while).

The search is for text between START_PATTERN and END_PATTERN1

Having a file structured like this:

```
text
text
...
START_PATTERN
line1
line2
END_PATTERN2
text
text
...
START_PATTERN
line1
line2
END_PATTERN1
text
text
...
```

The task would be to restart search if END_PATTERN2 is found. Thus the command output should be:

```
START_PATTERN
line1
line2
END_PATTERN1
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line should work for your example:

```
 tac file|sed '/END_PATTERN1/,/START_PAT/!d'|tac
```

test: (I added `xx` to the expected block lines):

```
kent$  cat f
text
text
...
START_PATTERN
line1
line2
END_PATTERN2
text
text
...
START_PATTERN
xxline1
xxline2
END_PATTERN1
text


kent$  tac f|sed '/END_PATTERN1/,/START_PAT/!d'|tac
START_PATTERN
xxline1
xxline2
END_PATTERN1
```

### Edit

take only the first match, with awk only:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}
     /START_PAT/{s=NR}
     /END_PATTERN2/{s=0}
     /END_PATTERN1/{exit}
     END{for(i=s;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Yes, it works. However there is one more condition, to be the first match. It was my mistake that I specified this only in the title.

Comment: I would like to add one more condition. END_PATTERN2=NoOfDevices different than X. Where X is a fixed given value. END_PATTERN1=NoOfDevices=X. Can you provide any input regarding this? Thank you!

Comment: @J.E it is the matter of regex pattern, if I understood you right. I would suggest you editing the question example, or open another question regarding the new requirement. I cannot understand the example in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about this by keeping a buffer of lines after the first pattern is found and resetting it if `END_PATTERN2` is found:

```
awk 'x { next }
/START_PATTERN/ { n = 1; f = 1 } 
f { lines[n++] = $0 } 
/END_PATTERN1/ { f = 0; x = 1 } 
/END_PATTERN2/ { n = 1; f = 0 } 
END { for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) print lines[i] }' file
```

`f` is a flag to determine whether to save the current line to the buffer `lines`. `n` is a counter used to index the buffer. Once the file is processed, the first `n` lines in the buffer are printed.

I've also added a variable `x` which, once set, causes all lines to be skipped. This means that only the first matching block will be saved.

Comment: The code before edit did not seemed to work for me but the last one is exactly what I was looking for. Placing x {next} as the first statement means that after /END_PATTERN1/ is found the next rules are not applied for any new records? Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/START_PATTERN/!d;:a;N;/END_PATTERN2/d;/END_PATTERN1/!ba;p;d' file
```

Use the `-n` grep-like switch. Start collecting lines on finding `START_PATTERN`. Delete the collection if `END_PATTERN2` is found. On finding `END_PATTERN1` print the lines.